# Solution on second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

I consider the following ODE:
$$
f''(x) = (A e^{x} + B)f'(x) + C e^{x} f(x),
$$
for some constants $A$, $B$ and $C$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

I want to find a general solution to this equation.
I used WolframAlpha website (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%27%27%28x%29+%3D+%28A+e%5E%28x%29+%2B+B%29f%27%28x%29+%2B+C+e%5E%28x%29+f%28x%29) and it returned me the following answer
$$
f(x) = (-1)^B c_2 A^B C^{-B} (C e^x)^B {_1F_1}\left(B + \frac{C}{A}; B + 1; A e^x\right) + c_1 {_1F_1}\left(\frac{C}{A}; 1 - B; A e^x\right),
$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are the constants that can be found based on the initial value conditions, while ${_1F_1}(a; b; x)$ is the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function.

I am not very familiar with the methods of solving such ODE.

However, I am curious about the step by step solution, so in other words how can we obtain the solution presented above?

Comment: maybe you could take its Laplace transform to simplify it algebraically?

Comment: Take $X = A e^x$ and $F(X) = f(x)$, you'll get Kummer's equation
$$X F''(X) + (1 - B - X) F'(X) - \frac C A F(X) = 0.$$

Comment: @Maxim, thank you, you helped me. I have one more question. Am I right that for a similar equation of the form $f''(x) = B f'(x) + (De^x+E)f(x)$ I can substitute X=De^x+E and then I obtain the ${_0 F_1}$ equation?